# PostgreSQL SELECT DISTINCT on Composite Primary key

Tags: postgresql, composite-primary-key

I have table with this structure:

```
Column    |  Type |
id        | int   | 
version   | int   |
status_id | int   |  // can be 1 active, 2 suspended, 3 removed
update    | Timestamp |
position  | Geometry  |

Indexes:
"PK_poi" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, version)
```

So this is my table structure, basically something will happen at Location , i will create it, then something else will happen and I will update the event with new version.

So data will be like

```
 id         |  version  | status_id |  update              | position
 1          |  1        |   1       |  2018-09-17 10:52:48 | x,y 
 2          |  1        |   1       |  2018-09-17 10:52:48 | x,y
 2          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 11:02:48 | x,y
 2          |  3        |   2       |  2018-09-17 11:22:48 | x,y
 1          |  2        |   2       |  2018-09-17 11:52:48 | x,y
 2          |  4        |   1       |  2018-09-17 12:52:48 | x,y
 1          |  3        |   3       |  2018-09-17 12:52:48 | x,y
 2          |  5        |   3       |  2018-09-17 13:52:48 | x,y
 3          |  1        |   1       |  2018-09-17 14:52:48 | x,y
 3          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 14:52:48 | x,y
 4          |  1        |   1       |  2018-09-17 16:52:48 | x,y
 4          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 16:52:48 | x,y
```

So I am trying to make a distint select, that returns me the "latest" version within a specified time-interval, based on the timestamp. But only if the "latest" version is not with status - suspended or removed.

So if at 17:52 I query the DB and I say  give me the latest events within the last hour, i would expect:

```
  id         |  version  | status_id |  update              | position
  4          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 16:52:48 | x,y
```

if I say however, give me the latest events from the last 24h, I would expect

```
  id         |  version  | status_id |  update              | position
  3          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 14:52:48 | x,y
  4          |  2        |   1       |  2018-09-17 16:52:48 | x,y
```

I am very confused how to do this, because of the composite key. Can you please give pointers on what exactly should I read?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number` to get the latest event for each location.

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "update" DESC ) as rn
                                          -- ^^^ create a group for each id
       FROM yourTable           
       WHERE status_id = 1
         -- optional if you want the events in a time range
         AND "update" > current_timestamp - interval '1 day -- filter the last 24 h events
     ) as Q

-- optional if you want all events remove it.
WHERE rn = 1 -- filter the last one of each id because is order by update desc
```

Comment: This definitely gave me a node in the right direction. 2 minor edits, and I can accept it as an aswer:
1. DATE_SUB is MySQL function, for Postgres use  WHERE "update" > (current_timestamp  - interval '1 day')
2. WHERE rn=1, selects the latest row number, for the specified time filter I have selected, however I needed it to select not only for the time filter but also for status_id = 1, which are the events that are still active.

Comment: Sorry is fixed now. I just google postgres last 24h and that was what i got. Didn't check twice.